# UR10 tool flange 24V power control

Tags: ros, ur-modern-driver, ros-kinetic, rosservices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i have been working on controlling a relay with the power output of the UR10 flange connector.
i recently got the ur_modern_driver/io_states publisher working and noticed that it does not publish the voltage that is on the output of said pin. The voltage on that pin can only be 0,12 or 24. I know that because with the teach panel i can set that output to those values. So now i do not know if i can use the ur_msgs service of SetIO.srv to set this output.

Do i need to program this myself or is this possible? I have been looking for a long time and cannot find documentation that says if this is possible.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320110/ur10-tool-flange-24v-power-control/) by [stefvanlierop](https://answers.ros.org/users/40682/stefvanlierop/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2019-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not well documented, but the [SetIO](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/ur_msgs/html/srv/SetIO.html) service should allow you to configure the tool voltage when you specify the `FUN_SET_TOOL_VOLTAGE` for `fun`, and then setting `state` to either `0`, `12` or `24`.

Some pseudo-code (neither Python nor C++):

```
req = SetIO()
req.fun = SetIO.FUN_SET_TOOL_VOLTAGE
req.state = 12
```

This would set the tool voltage to 12V after invoking the service.

---

Edit:

> I have been looking for a long time and cannot find documentation that says if this is possible.

I've submitted [ros-industrial/universal_robot#415](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/pull/415) to clarify the use of `SetIO` a bit.

Once that gets merged, the code changes slightly (constants added):

```
req = SetIO()
req.fun = SetIO.FUN_SET_TOOL_VOLTAGE
req.state = SetIO.STATE_TOOL_VOLTAGE_12V
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-02**:
For reference: [this](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ur_modern_driver/blob/7fae9f236e9557eb09e5e6554abe54da9de8f24a/include/ur_modern_driver/ros/io_service.h#L39-L60) is where the driver processes the incoming service request, and [this](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ur_modern_driver/blob/7fae9f236e9557eb09e5e6554abe54da9de8f24a/src/ur/commander.cpp#L49) is where the tool voltage request is processed.

**Comment by [stefvanlierop](https://answers.ros.org/users/40682/stefvanlierop/) on 2019-04-02**:
yes that worked, thank you very much